# Appending new Elements to Objects in Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, google-custom-search

I've been puzzling over this loop for a few days and can't quite get to what I need.

I loop over my array of search results (`mdb_results`) and extract from each object a `.name` to use as a `_search` term in a Google CSE Image Search.

Th CSE returns another array (`cse`) which I want to append to the object from which I extracted the `_search` term (`mdb_results[i]`).

```
router.get('/json', function(req, res, next) {
var ImageSearch = require('node-google-image-search');
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db){
  db.collection('mycatalog')
    .find({$text: {$search:"FOO" }})
    .toArray(function(err, mdb_results){    
        for (var i=0; i<mdb_results.length; i++){           
            var _search =  mdb_results[i].name ;

            ImageSearch(_search, function(cse){

               // How to add cse.img to mdb_results[i].images ??
               //    mdb_results[i].images = cse;
               // gives undefined

            },0,2);  
        };
        res.send(mdb_results);
        });
    });
});
```

My initial `mdb_results` looks like this.

```
[{"name":"FOO"},{"name":"FOOOO"}]
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this,

```
[{"name":"FOO", 
  "images":[{"img1":"http://thumbnail1"},{"img2":"http://thumbnail2"}]
},
{"name":"FOOOO", 
  "images":[{"img1":"http://thumbnaila"},{"img2":"http://thumbnailb"}]
}]
```

Can anyone show me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're expecting an asynchronous operation to work synchronously:

```
router.get('/json', function(req, res, next) {
var ImageSearch = require('node-google-image-search');
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db){
  db.collection('mycatalog')
    .find({$text: {$search:"FOO" }})
    .toArray(function(err, mdb_results){    
        for (var i=0; i<mdb_results.length; i++){           
            var _search =  mdb_results[i].name ;
            // This search is asynchronous, it won't have returned by the time
            // you return the result below.
            ImageSearch(_search, function(cse){

               // How to add cse.img to mdb_results[i].images ??
               //    mdb_results[i].images = cse;
               // gives undefined

            },0,2);  
        };
        // At this point, ImageSearch has been called, but has not returned results.
        res.send(mdb_results);
        });
    });
});
```

You're going to need to use promises or the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

Here's an example:

```
router.get('/json', function(req, res, next) {
var ImageSearch = require('node-google-image-search');
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err,db){
  db.collection('mycatalog')
    .find({$text: {$search:"FOO" }})
    .toArray(function(err, mdb_results){
        // async.forEach will iterate through an array and perform an asynchronous action.
        // It waits for you to call callback() to indicate that you are done
        // rather than waiting for it to execute synchronously.
        async.forEach(mdb_results, function (result, callback) {
            ImageSearch(result.name, function(cse){
               // This code doesn't get executed until the network call returns results.
               result.images = cse;
               // This indicate that you are done with this iteration.
               return callback();
            },0,2);  
        },
        // This gets call once callback() is called for each element in the array,
        // so this only gets fired after ImageSearch returns you results.
        function (err) {
            res.send(mdb_results);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This works and I accepted your answer - Thank you. Would you mind elaborating a little on what's going on with `cb`? Despite it working, I'm struggling to understand what's taking place.

Comment: I updated the post to try to elaborate. Understanding how callbacks work in NodeJS is critical to understanding what's going on here. The callback is used to indicate that you're done working.

Comment: Thanks for the annotations. I'm still struggling with `return callback()` which appears to be a call to itself? We pass `callback` into the enclosing function and then call it without any function definition for `callback`. If the answer is too complex for a comment, can you recommend a resource where I can educate myself?

Comment: [This article covers the content.](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/javascript-callbacks/) You provide a function that takes the result and a callback as arguments. The callback is a function that the async library passes in. Async waits for your to call that function to acknowledge that you're done doing asynchronous work. Once you've called `callback()` in every iteration, Async knows you're done. If you need more information, look for more articles on Nodejs callbacks. It's difficult to wrap your head around, but essential to Nodejs programming.